# Why doesn't my json get inserted into the site (NodeJS Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

So I've made a fetch call that that is supposed to get additional results if the user scrolls to the bottom and wants more content. It calls a function that retrieves those SQL results and sends them back in JSON.
The data is initially loaded in with an express forEach loop so I planned to just send in the new data so it can then do the same but it refreshes the page and just gives plain JSON without any of my styles or HTML.
I've also tried to insert it in with a loadIntoSection function but also had no luck.
What did I do wrong?

The fetch:

```
function getPosts(){
    fetch('localhost:8003/load/:sort/:offset')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => loadPostsIntoSection(data));
}
```

The route:

```
router.get('/load/:offset/:sort', (req, res, next) => {

  const temp = authController.posts(req.params.offset, req.params.sort); // this returns sql query results and works propperly
  temp.then(results => res.json(results));

});
```

HTML/EJS where it's supposed to load:

```
<div class="container">
    <%
    if(results.lenght != 0){
        results.forEach(function(results){
    %>

    <div class="post">
        <div class="meta">
            <div class="op"><%= results.username %></div>
            <div class="date"><%= results.date %></div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="post-title"><%= results.title %></h2>
        <div class="content">
            <p class="post-content"><%= results.content %></p>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <% })} else { %>
        locals.message1 = 'No posts found :(';
    <% } %>

</div>
```

This is what I also tried when the loop didn't work:

```
function loadPostsIntoSection(data){
  let html = "";
  data.forEach(function(post){
    html += `<div class="post">`;
        html += `<div class="meta">`;
        html += `<div class="op">${data.username}</div>`;
        html += `<div class="date">${data.time}</div>`;
    html += `</div>`;
    html += `<h2 class="post-title">${data.title}</h2>`;
    html += `<div class="content">`;
        html += `<p class="post-content">${data.content}</p>`;
    html += `</div>`;
    html += `<div class="attachment-container">`;
        if(results.audio == 0) {
            html =+ `<img src="${data.user_file}" class="attachment"></img>`;
        }
        else if (results.audio == 1){
            html += `<audio controls autoplay class="attachment"><source src="${data.user_file}" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>`;
        }
    html += `</div>`;
    html += `<%- include ("modules/social.ejs") %>`
    html += `</div>`;
    });
    document.querySelector('.container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}
```

Comment: Typo: `results.lenght` you misspelled `length`

Comment: In the EJS you have `results.date`, but in `forEach` you have `data.time`. Is the column named `date` or `time`?

Comment: I can't see any reason why you should be seeing the raw JSON. It sounds like you may be submitting a form that points to the controller, instead of just using the AJAX. Make sure you use `event.preventDefault()` to disable form submission.